# $f:]0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ has neither a maximum nor minimum proof

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> Prove that the function $f:]0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ has neither a maximum nor minimum.

I have tried to answer this question with the Weierstrass theorem

> Theorem: Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Therefore  there are $a$ and $b\in X$, so that $f(a)=\min\{f(x):x\in X\}$, and $f(b)=\max\{f(x):x\in X\}$.

I know by Heine-Borel theorem that $]0,1]$ is not compact. However I cannot see why the function $f:]0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ has neither a maximum nor minimum.

**Question:**

The function $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R},x\to\frac{1}{x}$ has no maximum because x never reaches 0. But if I think of an arbitrary function defined on (0,1), I cannot see why the maximum or minimum cannot be attain in a point $c\in(0,1)$(c will never be 1 or 0). What am I doing wrong?

How can I prove the claim?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There's something missing from the question---otherwise it is nonsense. For example clearly $f(x) = x$ attains its maximum of 1 on $(0,1]$.

Comment: But Is there a function that could have reached it sooner?

Comment: Yes there is a big difference between "can this happen and if so give a counterexample" versus "this always happens so prove it."

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to state is that there is a function that doesn't reach is supremum/infimum.
Otherwise there is the easy example $f(x) = 0$ which reaches both its maximum and minimum in $\frac{1}{2}$.
So you can take the function $g(x) = \frac{1}{x} sin(\frac{1}{x})$.